# replay pcap (wireshark) captured files from commandline

Tags: c#, command-line, wireshark, pcap

I've got software that listens for SNMP Traps and performs certain functions on receiving them. for testing, I am able to replay pcap files from wireshark using playcap, but I'd like to automate this testing and execute specific files and then test the results for what is expected behaviour.

I've played around with playcap and see that if I run playcap from commandline, it's first parameter is the filename. What seems to be missing is the step of specifying which interface to play the file on and actually running the file. adding additional params at commandline doesn't have any apparent affect. (this was all tested within windows).

Any alternate methods of replaying pcap files that could be executed from commandline would be great. Please consider that I need to add this to my automated testing of a windows based system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`playcap` indeed accepts no other arguments than the file. There's some [links on the Wireshark wiki to other tools](http://wiki.wireshark.org/Tools) (under "traffic generators"), it looks like [Bit-Twist](http://bittwist.sourceforge.net/) might serve your needs. Disclaimer: no personal experience.